# Getting NSNetServices from device found by ARP

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, bonjour

So I am able to look up different devices connected to my network via ARP - but was wondering if it was possible to selectively find out if any of these devices have Bonjour services broadcasting.

Example, so I find a computer at ip address: 10.15.232.29 - is there any way to figure out if I can use NSNetServiceBrowser to find all NSNetservices associated with this address?

thanks!